# import repository feature in gerrit

Tags: gerrit

I have recently switched from gitlab to gerrit and was wondering if there is any feature of importing existing repositories in gerrit (like in gitlab create new project page).

According to the documentation we can ssh the repos after creating a new project, but what I want is to hook the new project with the existing repo such that any new commit in the repo may trigger creation of a new patch set for code review in gerrit.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Gerrit wants to manage your repositories. It needs to do this for its own hooks to fire, and for the magical `refs/for/foo` branches to work.

You're going to have to push your repositories to Gerrit, and submit your code reviews there.

You *could* create a `ref-updated` hook in your original repository which looks at the incoming patches and creates Gerrit review requests for them, but this is going to be the script you indicated not wanting to write.

Comment: borealid, i am unable to understand what you refer to, can you be more elaborate ,thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no out-of-the-box solution for the use case that you mention

There is a [plugin that does something similar for Github projects](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/#/admin/projects/plugins/github) so it's likely to be possible to do something similar for Gitlab.